# Windows Service Bus - AMQP - Java

Tags: java, .net, amqp, azureservicebus

I´m developing a Client that reads a message from the **Windows Service Bus**, which was sent using .NET. The client is developed using Java and as far as I Know it creates the session, but when it gets to creates the consumers throws a JMSException which only tells me the followin message: amqp:not-allowed

Any clue?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems some features, related to sessions are not supported when using AMQP on Service Bus for Windows Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj841075.aspx

Are you using some of the features below ?

The following features of the Service Bus .NET API are not currently supported when using AMQP:

- Transactions.
- Send via transfer destination.
- Receive by message sequence number.
- Message and session browse.
- Session state.
- Batch-based APIs.
- Scaled-out receive.
- Runtime manipulation of subscription rules.
- Session lock renewal.